# How to type shortcode-like text in WordPress TinyMCE visual editor?

Tags: shortcode, tinymce, visual-editor

Suppose, I have a plugin which is offering a shortcode for its users: `[my-shortcode]`. Now I want to post an advertisement in a page of my WordPress powered blog like the following:

> Hey you can use the plugin using the `[my-shortcode]` into any page/post.

If I write so, on the front end WordPress thinks it's a shortcode, it tries executing this, and showing an ugly white blank block there. So I switched to the **HTML mode** of the editor, and wrap the text like this:

```
<code>[my-shortcode]</code>
```

Without switching back to the visual editor if I update the page, and see the front end, it's working just fine. But if now I need the visual editor for further editing [visually], and switch back to the visual editor again TinyMCE can't understand that it's a simple text, not a shortcode, and the same massacre happens again. :(

Even if I want to write something, anything with a third bracket like:

> Do something [once] and go...

WordPress can't understand it's a simple text. :(

How can I handle situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double third brackets then. In visual editor:

```
[[my-shortcode]]
```

To show shortcode as a *code*, in HTML/Text mode:

```
<code>[[my-shortcode]]</code>
```

And you can even write anything with a third bracket in this way:

> Do something [[once]] and go...

*<sub>suggested by [SergeyBiryukov](https://profiles.wordpress.org/SergeyBiryukov)</sub>